# Which offers better performance: A single JMS topic with a switch statement, or individual topics?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, scalability, spring-jms

I'm writing a Spring Boot application that will listen on one or more JMS topics. We've chosen ActiveMQ for our JMS implementation.

Our main concerns are performance and scalability. We're expecting potentially thousands of messages to arrive every second. We've come up with two alternatives:

1. Use a single topic and a single @JmsListener method. Inside the listener, inspect a JMS property to determine the correct strategy for handling the message.

   ```
   @JmsListener(destination = "response", containerFactory = "myTopicFactory")
   public void onMessage(Message message) throws IOException {
       message.getProperty("message.type")
       JmsHandler handler = messageStrategyMap.get(messageType);
       handler.handle(message);
   }
   ```
2. Use multiple topics and multiple @JmsListener methods. No switching logic is needed in this case.

   ```
   @JmsListener(destination = "responseType1", containerFactory = "myTopicFactory")
   public void onMessage1(Message message) throws IOException {
       // Handle message type 1
   }

   @JmsListener(destination = "responseType2", containerFactory = "myTopicFactory")
   public void onMessage2(Message message) throws IOException {
       // Handle message type 2
   }
   ```

An advantage of approach #1 is that there's no need to manage resources for multiple destinations; there's only only one destination. This also means that the collaborating systems only need to know about a single topic.

An advantage of approach #2 is that there's no need for any type of switching logic. Any message coming in on topic A has a payload formatted specifically for topic A. The concern with this approach is that resources for handling incoming messages might not be allocated efficiently between the different JMS listeners.

In addition, any advice on container factory configuration is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on message size and volume. With multiple listeners you are also getting multiple threads, so that may run faster up until the drop-off of having lots of topics (and therefore threads). I suggest setting up a quick test and benchmark on your representative system and you'll be armed with firm numbers to compare.